# how will I be able to choose the right parameters and the structure of a neural networks during the training phase?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to train a neural network in a supervised learning which has as input `x_train` a list of 100 list each containing 2000 column ....... and a target output `y_train` which has a list of 100 list also but contains each 20 column.

This is what `x_train` and `y_train` look like:

[image]

here is the neural networks that I created :

```
dnnmodel = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
dnnmodel.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, input_dim = len(id2word), activation='relu'))
dnnmodel.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
dnnmodel. compile ( loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(), optimizer = 'adam' , metrics = [ 'accuracy' ])
```

during the training phase I cannot choose the right number of neurons, layers and the activation and loss functions, since the accurency and loss values are not at all reasonable. .... can someone help me please?

Here is the display after the execution:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct method or formula to decide the correct number of layers or neurons or any other functions you use in your model. It all comes down experimentation and what works best for your data and the problem that you are trying to solve.

Here are some tips:
`sigmoid, tanh` = These activations are generally not used in hidden layers as their computed slopes or gradient is very small. So the model can take a long to converge.

`Relu, elu, leaky relu` - These activations can be used used in hidden layers as they have steep slope compared to others so the training process is fast. Relu is commonly used.

`Layers`: The more layers you add the deeper you make your neural network. Deeper neural networks are able to learn complex features about your data but they are prone to overfitting. Also, Deep Neural Network suffers from problems like vanishing gradient or exploding gradients. Fewer layers mean fewer params to learn and prone to underfitting.

`Loss Function` - Loss function depends on the problem you are trying to solve.
**For classification**
If y_label is categorical go for categorical_cross_entropy
If y_label is discreet go for sparse_categorical_cross_entropy
**For regression problems**
Use Rmse or MSE

Coming to the training logs. Your model is training as you can see the loss at each epoch less than the previous one. You should train your model for more epochs in order to see improvements in your accuracy.

Comment: Can you plz accept and upvote the answer if it worked.